# weighted correlation matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

in general i know that i can easily calculate correlation matrix in matlab,there is a lot of function for this,but what about weighted correlation?i found this matlab file

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20846-weighted-correlation-matrix/content/weightedcorrs.m

but  how does  choosing weights depend on persons intuition or it is standard?

let say we have

```
x = randn(30,4)

x =

    0.5377    0.8884   -1.0891   -1.1480
    1.8339   -1.1471    0.0326    0.1049
   -2.2588   -1.0689    0.5525    0.7223
    0.8622   -0.8095    1.1006    2.5855
    0.3188   -2.9443    1.5442   -0.6669
   -1.3077    1.4384    0.0859    0.1873
   -0.4336    0.3252   -1.4916   -0.0825
    0.3426   -0.7549   -0.7423   -1.9330
    3.5784    1.3703   -1.0616   -0.4390
    2.7694   -1.7115    2.3505   -1.7947
   -1.3499   -0.1022   -0.6156    0.8404
    3.0349   -0.2414    0.7481   -0.8880
    0.7254    0.3192   -0.1924    0.1001
   -0.0631    0.3129    0.8886   -0.5445
    0.7147   -0.8649   -0.7648    0.3035
   -0.2050   -0.0301   -1.4023   -0.6003
   -0.1241   -0.1649   -1.4224    0.4900
    1.4897    0.6277    0.4882    0.7394
    1.4090    1.0933   -0.1774    1.7119
    1.4172    1.1093   -0.1961   -0.1941
    0.6715   -0.8637    1.4193   -2.1384
   -1.2075    0.0774    0.2916   -0.8396
    0.7172   -1.2141    0.1978    1.3546
    1.6302   -1.1135    1.5877   -1.0722
    0.4889   -0.0068   -0.8045    0.9610
    1.0347    1.5326    0.6966    0.1240
    0.7269   -0.7697    0.8351    1.4367
   -0.3034    0.3714   -0.2437   -1.9609
    0.2939   -0.2256    0.2157   -0.1977
   -0.7873    1.1174   -1.1658   -1.2078
```

and we have done

x(:,4) = sum(x,2);   % Introduce correlation.
[r,p] = corrcoef(x)  % Compute sample correlation and p-values.

and  got

```
r =

    1.0000   -0.0352    0.2673    0.6901
   -0.0352    1.0000   -0.5101    0.2617
    0.2673   -0.5101    1.0000    0.3504
    0.6901    0.2617    0.3504    1.0000
```

it is unweighted correlation,but how can i do  weighted correlation with help of matlab file?please help me

Comment: The `weightedcorrs.m` function is no longer available at Matlab Central. An alternative is the QCP toolbox: https://github.com/BMSQSP/QSPToolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function needs the weights of each observation as input. How you choose them is upto you.

If these were outputs of a simulation for example, you could let the weights be the number of performed iterations. If they were stock results, consider using the value in the portfolio. However, there is no standard way to get the 'best' weights in general. Just consider that a value that is more reliable should typically get more weight.

Comment: @datodatuashvili If you are looking for the syntax just try `help weightcorrs` In your case you don't seem to know what weights you want so just give them all equal weights to start with: `R = weightedcorrs(x, ones(size(x,1),1))` Or increasing weights: `weightedcorrs(x, 1:30)`

Comment: but this function does not exist in matlab

Comment: i am trying to create myself from this site http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient

Comment: @datodatuashvili It is a file exchange submission. The link that you refer to in the question has a download button on the righthand side. Download it and make sure it is saved somewhere on your matlab `path`.

Comment: but then how to apply in my case?

Comment: i have created my self from wikipedia,now i will post question related to matrix